# How to check that the entered text is in arabic from arabic keyboard in UITextField programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextfield

How can we check that the selected keyboard is not English and it is in Arabic. So on later stage i convert the Arabic digits to English numeric digits for better search on web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can know the current language of the phone. By the following code

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray *languages = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    NSString *currentLanguage = [languages objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"Current Locale: %@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]);
    NSLog(@"Current language: %@", currentLanguage);
```

If it is in Arabic, that means the keyboard will also comes in Arabic and user will enter the Arabic text.